# Selecting a subset of a sqlite database with dplyr

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr

I'm trying to pull down a subset of rows in a sqlite database using dplyr.  Since `slice` doesn't work with `tbl_sql` objects, I'm using the window function `row_number`.  But I get the following error:

```
Source: sqlite 3.8.6  
[/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/dplyr/db/nycflights13.sqlite]
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
error in statement: no such function: ROW_NUMBER
```

dplyr version 0.4.3.9000, RSQLite version 1.0.0.  Reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)

flights_sqlite <- tbl(nycflights13_sqlite(), "flights")

filter(flights_sqlite, row_number(month) == 1L) %>% collect()
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably there's a more efficient and faster way, but `head` seems to do the job.

> To extract **first n rows**, for instance first 10 records:

```
head(flights_sqlite, 10) %>% collect()
```

Output:

```
   year month day dep_time dep_delay arr_time arr_delay carrier tailnum flight origin dest air_time distance hour minute
1  2013     1   1      517         2      830        11      UA  N14228   1545    EWR  IAH      227     1400    5     17
2  2013     1   1      533         4      850        20      UA  N24211   1714    LGA  IAH      227     1416    5     33
3  2013     1   1      542         2      923        33      AA  N619AA   1141    JFK  MIA      160     1089    5     42
4  2013     1   1      544        -1     1004       -18      B6  N804JB    725    JFK  BQN      183     1576    5     44
5  2013     1   1      554        -6      812       -25      DL  N668DN    461    LGA  ATL      116      762    5     54
6  2013     1   1      554        -4      740        12      UA  N39463   1696    EWR  ORD      150      719    5     54
7  2013     1   1      555        -5      913        19      B6  N516JB    507    EWR  FLL      158     1065    5     55
8  2013     1   1      557        -3      709       -14      EV  N829AS   5708    LGA  IAD       53      229    5     57
9  2013     1   1      557        -3      838        -8      B6  N593JB     79    JFK  MCO      140      944    5     57
10 2013     1   1      558        -2      753         8      AA  N3ALAA    301    LGA  ORD      138      733    5     58
```

> A **percentage of the first rows**

```
head(flights_sqlite, nrow(flights_sqlite)*0.1) %>% collect()
```

> To **subset any specific number of rows**. For instance rows 578 and 579:

```
head(flights_sqlite, nrow(flights_sqlite))[578:579, ] %>% collect()
```

Output:

```
    year month day dep_time dep_delay arr_time arr_delay carrier tailnum flight origin dest air_time distance hour minute
578 2013     1   1     1701        -9     2026        11      AA  N3FUAA    695    JFK  AUS      247     1521   17      1
579 2013     1   1     1701         1     1856        16      UA  N418UA    689    LGA  ORD      144      733   17      1
```

Comment: Yep, that works-- but not what I wanted.  Basically, I want to only pull out 1, 100, 1,000, or N number of records rather than collecting the whole database.  So I don't want to filter on the value of 'month'-- I just want to `slice` out the first N rows.  Since sqlite databases don't have intrinsic row numbers though, the slice function won't work.  Sorry if that was unclear!

Comment: The motivation is that I'm working with a large database, and it takes to long to collect the entire thing into a data frame.  So I only want to fetch a chunk of the data at a given time.

Comment: @LauraHughes If you'd like to extract the first N rows, for instance 10 rows: `head(flights_sqlite, 10) %>% collect()` or a percentage of the database (10%): `head(flights_sqlite, nrow(flights_sqlite)*0.1)%>% collect()`

Comment: @LauraHughes I modified my answer. Does it solve your question?

Comment: Thanks for your help @mpalanco.  It sort of works; definitely provides the right output at the command line, but I'm interfacing with DT in Shiny, and for some reason it's only displaying only some of the columns (though if you further filter they're all there-- though that's also requerying the database).  I haven't had time to troubleshoot, but I'll let you know what I find.  Thanks again for all your help!